# FFMPEG trouble with mounted s3fs (fuse) drive "failed to rename file __.stream.tmp to __.stream: Operation not supported"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-streaming, fuse, s3fs

*** PLease this question is not about my ffmpeg command, but the fact that is stops when the output files goes to a mounted s3fs...

CONTEXT : convert a video when the output file goes to a mounted bucket via s3fs (fuse) [linux]

CONTEXT 2 : no error with my ffmpeg command, when I do it locally => all ok. But when it goes to a s3fs mounted point I get the error.

FFPMEG COMMAND :

```
ffmpeg -i "/home/ffmpeg/112233.mov" 
-c:v libx264 -movflags +dash -preset fast 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ac 2 
-profile:v high -b:v 3369k -vf scale=-2:1080 
-bufsize 969k -hls_time 9 -hls_list_size 0 -g 30 
-start_number 0 -streaming 1 -hls_playlist 1 
-lhls 1 -hls_playlist_type event 
-f hls "/mnt/s3fs/test/112233.stream"
```

WHEN I TRY THIS FFMEG : local -> to -> local = ok

WHEN I TRY THIS FFMEG : local -> to -> s3fs = stops after few seconds with

```
"failed to rename file __.stream.tmp to __.stream: Operation not supported"
```

QUESTION 1 : is there a ffmpeg option to not rename (not create a .tmp but only .m3u8)?

QUESTION 2 : or is there an option to make ffmpeg continue when this error occurs ?

Comment: Can you run ffmpeg with strace to see which system call returns ENOTSUPP?  Also which version of s3fs are you using?

Comment: @AndrewGaul see my answer, the thing was `-hls_playlist_type event` was waiting the first segment to rename...

Comment: But this is a workaround -- s3fs has some underlying issue that prevents normal use.  Please follow up with a GitHub issue!

Comment: The original command works for me using ffmpeg and s3fs 1.90.

Answer (score 0):

I dig a bit on the web and found out that `-hls_playlist_type event` "waits" for completion of the first segment to "rename" the .tmp

replacing `-hls_playlist_type event` by `-hls_playlist_type vod` did the trick.

now the .m3u8 get created without the need to rename.

Comment: I also removed the `-hls_playlist_type` and it creates right away the .m3u8.tmp, with `-hls_playlist_type vod` it waits for the full transcode to finish to create the .m3u8

Comment: also the s3fs is pointing to a mount point that have hard time with rename... I do cp instead of mv....